# Bootstrap overlapping border with columns with no margin and padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border, overlapping

I have this annoying problem with the borders of the divs.
How can I avoid the borders overlapping each other?

This is my codepen where you can see the problem: 
http://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/Bzrgzx

```
.square {
    background-color: #595959;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s,color .3s;
    transition: background-color .3s,color .3s;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ffde14;
}

.square:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your border width is fixed you can avoid this by reducing the right margin of your bootstrap cols by the width of your border:

```
  & > [class^="col-"],
  & > [class*=" col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: -1px; /* <- */
  }
```